# how to set twice json object in android?

Tags: android, json

my tryouts but its give me error

**My JSON:**

```
{
    "status":true,
    "message":"Front About Found",
    "data":{
        "FrontAbout":{
            "ABOUT_ID":"1",
            "CONTENT":"and the arts. ",
            "SCHOOL_NAME":"The New School",
            "ADDRESS":" Western Corridor",
            "LOGO":"14643339731.png"
        }
    }
}
```

**My Sample code:**

```
{
    JSONArray jsonarray = jObj.getJSONArray("data");

    for (int z = 0; z < jsonarray.length(); z++) {

        JSONObject jobj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(z);

        JSONObject jobj_FrontAbout = jobj.getJSONObject("FrontAbout");

        school = jobj_FrontAbout.getString("SCHOOL_NAME");
        add = jobj_FrontAbout.getString("ADDRESS");
        phone = jobj_FrontAbout.getString("CONTACT_NO");
        email = jobj_FrontAbout.getString("EMAIL");
        cont = jobj_FrontAbout.getString("CONTENT");
        image = jobj_FrontAbout.getString("LOGO");

        setData();

        loadingView.dismiss();

    }

    loadingView.dismiss();
    if (loadingView != null && loadingView.isShowing()) {
        loadingView.dismiss();
    }
}
```

its give me error " JSONObject can not to be converted to JSONArray "

i want to simple set in textview not in array 
please give me solution

Comment: Your Json string is invalid. Correct that first

Comment: final JSONArray jObject = new JSONArray("data");

Comment: `"data": { "FrontAbout"` This "data" is an JSON object and not an array. A json array is like `"data": [...]`. Use `JSONObject jsonarray = jObj.getJSONObject("data");`

Comment: Hei man , can you please edit the provided error , We cant help you if you give us wrong info . your json has some formatting error . you better test your json with [link](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org) and save your json and send us the saved link of your json

Comment: String can not be converted in to JSONArray – Surya Bondada

Comment: From the response given I am only seeing JsonObjects..
Your "data" is also a JSONObject  not JSONArray .@kushpf comment is the correct one.

Comment: @niravshah i was  posted  your ans check it. i think u didnt see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can  parse like this.

```
JSONObject jobj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(z);
status=jobj.getBoolean("status");
message=jobj.getString("message");
                        JSONObject dataObject = jobj.getJSONObject("data");
                        JSONObject frontAboutObject = dataObject.getJSONObject("FrontAbout");

                        school = frontAboutObject.getString("SCHOOL_NAME");
                        add = frontAboutObject.getString("ADDRESS");
                        phone = frontAboutObject.getString("CONTACT_NO");
                        email = frontAboutObject.getString("EMAIL");
                        cont = frontAboutObject.getString("CONTENT");
                        image = frontAboutObject.getString("LOGO");
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are you are parsing for "data" as a JSOnArray Although "data" is a JSONObJect .

JSON nodes will start with a square bracket or with a curly bracket. The difference between [ and { is, the square bracket ([) represents starting of an `JSONArray` node whereas curly bracket ({) represents `JSONObject`.

```
{
JSONObject dataJsonObject = jObj.getJSONObject("data");

for (int z = 0; z < dataJsonObject.length(); z++) {

    JSONObject jobj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(z);

    JSONObject jobj_FrontAbout = jobj.getJSONObject("FrontAbout");

    school = jobj_FrontAbout.getString("SCHOOL_NAME");
    add = jobj_FrontAbout.getString("ADDRESS");
    phone = jobj_FrontAbout.getString("CONTACT_NO");
    email = jobj_FrontAbout.getString("EMAIL");
    cont = jobj_FrontAbout.getString("CONTENT");
    image = jobj_FrontAbout.getString("LOGO");

    setData();

    loadingView.dismiss();

}

loadingView.dismiss();
if (loadingView != null && loadingView.isShowing()) {
    loadingView.dismiss();
}
```

}

HopeFully You will get rid of your error . CHEERS

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
JSONObject jsonObj= jObj.getJSONObject("your json string");
JSONObject jsonInnerObj= jsonObj.getJSONObject("data");
```

Comment: Accept my answer then :)